# html - iFrame/Object is not expanding to 100% height

Tags: html, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3

So, on my website, I decided to put a Phase Beam thingy as my picture. I couldn't use an `<img>` tag because it isn't an actual image. So I iframed it. I set width and height to 100%, but my height is not going to 100%.

[My Website](https://www.v33r.tk)

As you can see, the Phase Beam starts from the first `<div class="page-header page-banner"></div>`, and it goes halfway, and it doesn't reach the second `<div class="page-header page-banner">`.

[Example of Proper Image Placement](http://limetech.org)

How would I make the iFrame expand all the way to the second `<div class="page-header page-banner"></div>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the iframe parent div to `390px` :

```
<div style="height:390px" class="col-md-8">
```

And you'll get a perfect alignment with the `<div class="page-header page-banner">` div.

[image]

**Note :**

There is a typo in the iframe tag where the specified height is `height:100%px`.

Comment: I tired this, but the only problem is that the bottom line is not touching the iframe, like in the 2nd example.

Comment: I don't see any bottom line, are you talking about the copyright notice?  If so there is the `<div class="page-header page-banner"></div>` in your Web Site that it is not in the exemple.  This div adds space just before the copyright notice.

Comment: Yes, `<div class="page-header page-banner"></div>` is the bottom line, and the example website has it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I corrected my answer.

Comment: Nice, but how do i make it align to the line on top of the copyright? That grey line. Because it has to be aligned with that to have the mobile view working properly. And thanks for your help so far! :)

Comment: Looks like there is weird overlap in the example page with the image and the `<div class="page-header page-banner"></div>`.  Easy solution is to remove it (it looks useless anyway).  If you don't want to remove it you can try `.page-banner {margin: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;}`.

Comment: thanks, that worked, my title is kind messed up, but ill fix it somehow. Thanks:)